# ObjectDataSource.Insert always returning -1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, objectdatasource

Trying to get the new row ID, I have looked everywhere and tried the common solutions that seem to work for everyone else. I cannot change the database, but I do know that parameter VersionID is set with a scope Identity. the last line in the SP is return(@@VersionID)  I have also tried putting this on the inserted event

```
protected void VersionDataSource_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs    e)
{
    int returnValue = (int)e.OutputParameters;

}
```

however it always returns -1, I cannot seem to get the new row ID, I have tried making the parameter Direction output as well as returnValue. At a total loss, have spent the whole day on this crap.

Comment: How do you insert values to datasource?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Outputparameters is a dictionary, I would suggest

```
int returnValue = (int)e.OutputParameters["VersionID"].Value;
```

Comment: value is not a valid choice, I tried (int)e.OutputParameters["VersionID"] and got a null. I have skipped traced it in SQL and it returns the proper ID, the fundamental problem seems to be that it is returning the method returns a affected row count -1 means rowcount is set to false in SQL. Seriously going to pick up drinking again!

Comment: Are you sure VersionID is set in the proc then ?

Comment: INSERT INTO ...
stuff goes here
SET @@VersionID = scope_identity()
END

Part that blows is I cannot change the DB, just look at it, not that I know what changes would even be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the markup, but you should have a parameter defined as an output parameter:

```
<asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="VersionID"  Type="Int32" />
```

With the above, you should be able to get the outputted value like this:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) 
{ 
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameter["VersionID"].Value); 
}
```

Comment: I added the parameter in the markup however it is not a sqlDataSource, it is an ObjectDataSource based of a existing stored proc.

Comment: That's fine. It shouldn't really make a difference because it's still the same type of parameter. Why are you using an `ObjectDataSource`? Are you using EF or something?

Comment: Honestly, I had never used datasources before at my last job, I had been stuck doing legacy fixes... Boss told me to use object, so I used object...

Comment: Do you use any kind of ORM (Object Relational Mapper)? If not, you should probably use a `SqlDataSource` instead.

Comment: I talked the DB guy into adding another parameter and had him put OUTPUT after it then set it to match what we were trying to return. Added the parameter as output type and threw this after in the inserted
protected void VersionDataSource_Inserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
       versionID = (int)e.OutputParameters["VersionOutput"];
     
    }
9 hours for 1 asshat line of code...

Comment: thanks for not giving up on me, I knew they were crazy to promote me after only being 9 months out of school :-(

Comment: No worries man. I'm on my phone right now, but we'll get this figured out when I'm back at my computer.